# Is there support in python to *import* a gzipped file?

Tags: python, import, gzip

Assuming I have a gzipped `mymodule.py.gz` I hoped that python (maybe with some parameters) could import it with:

```
import mymodule
```

(I would imagine that when a .py file is not found, then .py.gz is looked for.)

or maybe there is a specific version of import:

```
gzimport mymodule
```

I would not want to uncompress the file if possible. I guess, I could just uncompress it (from within python maybe to /tmp) and import it as normal. But I would rather not do that if I do not have to.) Other compression formats would also be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned "*other compression formats would also be of interest*":

This actually works out of the box for .zip format. You just need to have the zipfile on the `sys.path` (just the same as any other directory containing .py files available for importing).

```
$ echo 'print("hello world")' > mymodule.py
$ zip -o example.zip mymodule.py 
  adding: example.py (stored 0%)
$ rm mymodule.py 
$ python3
Python 3.10.2 (main, Feb  2 2022, 06:19:27) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("example.zip")
>>> import mymodule
hello world
```

It works because there is a [zipimporter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html) active by default:

```
>>> mymodule
<module 'mymodule' from 'example.zip/mymodule.py'>
>>> mymodule.__loader__
<zipimporter object "example.zip/">
```

To get it working for .gz format, you could add support fairly easily by adding a gzip importer to the [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path).

Comment: "you could add support fairly easily by adding a gzip importer to the sys.meta_path." Is such an importer already implemented in an easily accessible way, or do you propose writing one from scratch? If the standard library provides one, why is it not active by default like the zip importer?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There isn't one in the standard library, but there might be one out there on PyPI already, I'm not sure. It would be pretty easy to write from scratch, anyway (just extract with stdlib [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) and then re-use the source file loader code).